onViewableItemsChanged won't update the viewableItem even though the currently visible item has changed
I am trying to build a workout tracking app. In it, I am displaying the user's exercises in a horizontal flatlist. I want the page indicator to display the currently viewable page. To do so, I am trying to use the 'onViewableItemsChanged' in the FlatList but for some reason, it won't update the currently viewable item.
import {
  Dimensions,
  FlatList,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { PageIndicator } from "react-native-page-indicator";

const styles = {
  setCol: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  prevCol: {
    flex: 2,
  },
  kgCol: {
    flex: 2,
  },
  repsCol: {
    flex: 1,
  },
};

const SetItem = ({ set }) => {
  const { width: screenWidth } = Dimensions.get("window");
  // console.log(`total: ${totalExercises} current:${current}`)

  return (
    <View
      style={{ width: screenWidth - 32 }}
      className="flex-1 justify-start items-center mt-2"
    >
      <View className="w-full flex justify-start items-start">
        <Text className="text-primary font-mregular text-md">{set.name}</Text>
      </View>
      <View className="flex justify-start items-center mt-2">
        <View>
          <View className="w-full flex-row justify-start items-center px-2">
            <Text
              style={styles.setCol}
              className="text-gray-500 text-left text-xs"
            >
              SET
            </Text>
            <Text
              style={styles.prevCol}
              className="text-gray-500 text-center text-xs"
            >
              PREV
            </Text>
            <Text
              style={styles.kgCol}
              className="text-gray-500 text-center text-xs"
            >
              KG
            </Text>
            <Text
              style={styles.repsCol}
              className="text-gray-500 text-right text-xs"
            >
              REPS
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        {set.sets.map((item, index) => (
          <View className="w-full flex-row justify-start items-center px-2">
            <Text style={styles.setCol} className="text-white text-left">
              {index + 1}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.prevCol} className="text-white text-center mt-1">
              ? x ?
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.kgCol} className="text-white text-center mt-1">
              {item.weight}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.repsCol} className="text-white text-right mt-1">
              {item.reps}
            </Text>
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const UserInClub = ({ user }) => {
  const [totalExercises, setTotalExercises] = useState(0);
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTotalExercises(user.exercises.length);
  }, []);

  // Handle the event when the FlatList viewable items change
  const viewableItemsChanged = ({ viewableItems }) => {
    if (viewableItems.length > 0) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(viewableItems));
      setCurrentIndex(viewableItems[0].index); // Update the index of the current exercise
    }
  };

  return (
    <View className="w-full flex justify-start items-center">
      <View className="w-full flex-row items-center justify-start space-x-3">
        <Image
          source={{ uri: user.img_url }}
          className="w-8 h-8 rounded-full"
          resizeMode="contain"
        />
        <Text className="font-mmedium text-md text-white">{user.username}</Text>
      </View>
      <FlatList
        data={user.exercises}
        horizontal
        pagingEnabled
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.$id}
        onViewableItemsChanged={viewableItemsChanged} // Attach the viewable items handler
        viewabilityConfig={{
          itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 70,
        }}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <SetItem key={item.$id} set={item} />}
      />
      <PageIndicator
        className="mt-2"
        count={totalExercises}
        current={currentIndex}
        color="#FFFFFF"
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default UserInClub;


Here's what the console.log in the viewableItemsChanged function displays on startup
 [{"index":0,"item":{"name":"Lat Pulldown","sets":[{"weight":"60","reps":"11","done":true},{"weight":"65","reps":"7","done":true},{"weight":"60","reps":"6","done":true}]},"isViewable":true}]

It doesn't get called afterwards no matter how many times the viewable items change.

Doesn’t the callback need to be in a ref.current?
